# Calculate time between steps in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I have an audit table that tracks the steps in a process and I need to track the time for each step. It used to be stored in MS SQL Server but is now stored in PostgreSQL.  I have the query from SQL server and have not been successful at converting it.  Here is the MS SQL working example: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/1b423/1

Here are the rules:

- The steps are not required to be sequential, so step 1 can happen
  after step 5.
- The records for an order are not stored sequentially by step
  or order, but rather are intermixed with other orders based upon
  the Time Entered.
- The sample data being ordered by Order Number then New is NOT
  normal and cannot be depended upon.
- Each step can be repeated for any given order, if repeated for an
  order, then sum the times by step.
- The starting step record is always null in the Old column
- Starting step is calculated as the time difference between
  when it is in the New column and when it is the value in the Old
  column for a given order.
- For the steps that the order never came out of, the time is computed
  up to the present moment
- A step can be repeated many times and am only looking for the total
  time spent in each step.

I cannot get the date difference to sum or handle the null old status value for the first step.  I get various forms of this error when running the following sql.

> ERROR:  function isnull(timestamp without time zone, timestamp with
> time zone) does not exist LINE 4:  sum(a1.timeentered -
> isnull(a2.timeentered,now())) as "tota...
> ^ HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

```
SELECT
    a1.ordernumber, 
    a1."new" AS "Step",
    sum(a1.timeentered - isnull(a2.timeentered,now())) as "total time"
FROM
    audittrail AS a1
    LEFT JOIN
    audittrail AS a2
    ON 
        a1."new" = a2."old" AND
        a1.ordernumber = a2.ordernumber
GROUP BY
    a1.ordernumber, 
    a1."new"
ORDER BY
    a1.ordernumber ASC
```

Here is the sample data as well as a link to a sample online: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/e6fd5a

```
 Old      New           Time Entered        Order Number
 NULL     Step 1        4/30/12 10:43       1C2014A
 Step 1   Step 2        5/2/12 10:17        1C2014A
 Step 2   Step 3        5/2/12 10:28        1C2014A
 Step 3   Step 4        5/2/12 11:14        1C2014A
 Step 4   Step 5        5/2/12 11:19        1C2014A
 Step 5   Step 9        5/3/12 11:23        1C2014A
 NULL     Step 1        5/18/12 15:49       1C2014B
 Step 1   Step 2        5/21/12 9:21        1C2014B
 Step 2   Step 3        5/21/12 9:34        1C2014B
 Step 3   Step 4        5/21/12 10:08       1C2014B
 Step 4   Step 5        5/21/12 10:09       1C2014B
 Step 5   Step 6        5/21/12 16:27       1C2014B
 Step 6   Step 9        5/21/12 18:07       1C2014B
 NULL     Step 1        6/12/12 10:28       1C2014C
 Step 1   Step 2        6/13/12 8:36        1C2014C
 Step 2   Step 3        6/13/12 9:05        1C2014C
 Step 3   Step 4        6/13/12 10:28       1C2014C
 Step 4   Step 6        6/13/12 10:50       1C2014C
 Step 6   Step 8        6/13/12 12:14       1C2014C
 Step 8   Step 4        6/13/12 15:13       1C2014C
 Step 4   Step 5        6/13/12 15:23       1C2014C
 Step 5   Step 8        6/13/12 15:30       1C2014C
 Step 8   Step 9        6/18/12 14:04       1C2014C
```

This is the expected result:

```
| OrderNumber |   Step | Total Time in Step (seconds) |
|-------------|--------|------------------------------|
|     1C2014A | Step 1 |                       171240 |
|     1C2014A | Step 2 |                          660 |
|     1C2014A | Step 3 |                         2760 |
|     1C2014A | Step 4 |                          300 |
|     1C2014A | Step 5 |                        86640 |
|     1C2014A | Step 9 |                    324902599 |
|     1C2014B | Step 1 |                       235920 |
|     1C2014B | Step 2 |                          780 |
|     1C2014B | Step 3 |                         2040 |
|     1C2014B | Step 4 |                           60 |
|     1C2014B | Step 5 |                        22680 |
|     1C2014B | Step 6 |                         6000 |
|     1C2014B | Step 9 |                    323323159 |
|     1C2014C | Step 1 |                        79680 |
|     1C2014C | Step 2 |                         1740 |
|     1C2014C | Step 3 |                         4980 |
|     1C2014C | Step 4 |                         3840 |
|     1C2014C | Step 5 |                          420 |
|     1C2014C | Step 6 |                         5040 |
|     1C2014C | Step 8 |                       875160 |
|     1C2014C | Step 9 |                    320918539 |
```

Comment: Change `[total time]` to `"total time"`. `" "` is the SQL standard for quoting identifiers. `[]` must be some SQL Server specific hack. I would advise taking a look at [SQL Syntax](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax.html) as you go through the conversion process.

Comment: Is it SQL Server or Postgres? It can't be both: Remove whichever tag does not apply.

Comment: Removed the brackets and used "" but that didn't change the message.  I removed SQL Server tag, I only had that there since it was a conversion from sql server to postgresql.

Comment: Missing parenthesis, should be: `...isnull(a2.timeentered,now())) as "total time"`

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be harder than I thought. This is the full query I used. It doesn't have the subsitution for `ISNULL` function, but it gets most of the way there. I used the `extract` function from [Date/Time Functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html). Specifically, to get everything in seconds, I used `extract(epoch from ...`

```
SELECT
    a1.ordernumber, 
    a1."new" AS "Step",
    sum(extract(epoch from a2.timeentered) - 
    extract(epoch from a1.timeentered)) as total_time
FROM
    audittrail AS a1
    LEFT JOIN
    audittrail AS a2
    ON 
        a1.new = a2.old AND
        a1.ordernumber = a2.ordernumber 
GROUP BY
    a1.ordernumber,
    a1.new
ORDER BY a1.ordernumber ASC
```

which gives

| ordernumber | Step | total_time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1C2014A | Step 1 | 171240 |
| 1C2014A | Step 2 | 660 |
| 1C2014A | Step 3 | 2760 |
| 1C2014A | Step 4 | 300 |
| 1C2014A | Step 5 | 86640 |
| 1C2014A | Step 9 | NULL |
| 1C2014B | Step 1 | 235920 |
| 1C2014B | Step 2 | 780 |
| 1C2014B | Step 3 | 2040 |
| 1C2014B | Step 4 | 60 |
| 1C2014B | Step 5 | 22680 |
| 1C2014B | Step 6 | 6000 |
| 1C2014B | Step 9 | NULL |
| 1C2014C | Step 1 | 79680 |
| 1C2014C | Step 2 | 1740 |
| 1C2014C | Step 3 | 4980 |
| 1C2014C | Step 4 | 3840 |
| 1C2014C | Step 5 | 420 |
| 1C2014C | Step 6 | 5040 |
| 1C2014C | Step 8 | 875160 |
| 1C2014C | Step 9 | NULL |

To me this calculation looks wrong. For me, it makes more sense (for example) for the entry for Step 3/Order 1C2014A, the total_time should be 11 minutes or 660 seconds. To achieve this, swap old and new in the join and swap a1 and a2 in the sum(part(epoch....) to become

```
SELECT
    a1.ordernumber, 
    a1.new AS Step,
    sum(extract(epoch from a1.timeentered) - 
    extract(epoch from a2.timeentered)) as total_time
FROM
    audittrail AS a1
    LEFT JOIN
    audittrail AS a2
    ON 
        a1.old = a2.new AND
        a1.ordernumber = a2.ordernumber 
GROUP BY
    a1.ordernumber,
    a1.new
ORDER BY a1.ordernumber ASC
```

Comment: Use coalesce() instead of isnull ()

Comment: Why should Step 3/1C2014A be 11 minutes? From `2012-05-02 10:28` to `2012-05-02 11:14:00` it's 46 minutes - https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=f02f64db946d3051bb049f8c61f8ba22

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, your looking at my preferred (second) solution. For me it makes more sense for Step3/C2014a to be counted from the **previous** value and not the next value. So from 2012-05-02 10:17 to 2012-05-02 10:28.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace `isnull` and `datediff` with equivalent PostgreSQL expressions in the second query line.

```sql
select a1.OrderNumber as "OrderNumber", a1.New as "Step", 
    extract('epoch' from 
            sum(coalesce(a2.TimeEntered, now()) - a1.TimeEntered))::integer 
    as "Total Time in Step (seconds)"
from AuditTrail a1
left join AuditTrail a2
  on a1.New = a2.Old 
  and a1.OrderNumber = a2.OrderNumber
group by a1.OrderNumber, a1.New
order by a1.OrderNumber;
```